# Scraping a table from a page using beautifulsoup, table is not found

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to scrape the table from
[here](http://www.payscale.com/college-salary-report/bachelors?page=65) but it seems to me that BeautifulSoup doesn't find any table.

I wrote:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

url = "http://www.payscale.com/college-salary-report/bachelors?page=65" 
r=requests.get(url)
data=r.text

soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'xml')
table=soup.find_all('table')
print table   #prints nothing..
```

Based on other similar questions, I assume that the HTML is broken in someway, but I'm not an expert..
Couldn't find an answer in those:
([Beautiful soup missing some html table tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39451810/beautiful-soup-missing-some-html-table-tags)), 
([Extracting a table from a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29375475/extracting-a-table-from-a-website)),
([Scraping a table using BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167106/scraping-a-table-using-beautifulsoup)), or even ([Python+BeautifulSoup: scraping a particular table from a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34664249/pythonbeautifulsoup-scraping-a-particular-table-from-a-webpage))

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I would print `data` and see if you find a table within that page.

Comment: Thank you @metama. I did so - the only thing is:
        <!-- Tablet Image -->

and bsoup wouldnt find it..

Also - if looking for table is not the way in this case, then how would you go about it? thanks!

Comment: there is no table tag in the page. All the table information is in script tag.

Comment: What information you need from the table ??

Comment: Thank you @KhairulBasarRofi . I need the table as it is.in CSV would be nice..

Comment: @oba2311 updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are parsing `html` but you used `xml` parser.
You should use `soup=BeautifulSoup(data,"html.parser")` 
Your necessary data is in `script` tag, in fact there is no `table` tag actually. So, you need to find texts inside `script`. 
**N.B: If you are using Python 2.x then use "HTMLParser" instead of "html.parser".**

Here is the code.

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.payscale.com/college-salary-report/bachelors?page=65" 
r=requests.get(url)
data=r.text

soup=BeautifulSoup(data,"html.parser")
scripts = soup.find_all("script")

file_name = open("table.csv","w",newline="")
writer = csv.writer(file_name)
list_to_write = []

list_to_write.append(["Rank","School Name","School Type","Early Career Median Pay","Mid-Career Median Pay","% High Job Meaning","% STEM"])

for script in scripts:
    text = script.text
    start = 0
    end = 0
    if(len(text) > 10000):
        while(start > -1):
            start = text.find('"School Name":"',start)
            if(start == -1):
                break
            start += len('"School Name":"')
            end = text.find('"',start)
            school_name = text[start:end]

            start = text.find('"Early Career Median Pay":"',start)
            start += len('"Early Career Median Pay":"')
            end = text.find('"',start)
            early_pay = text[start:end]

            start = text.find('"Mid-Career Median Pay":"',start)
            start += len('"Mid-Career Median Pay":"')
            end = text.find('"',start)
            mid_pay = text[start:end]

            start = text.find('"Rank":"',start)
            start += len('"Rank":"')
            end = text.find('"',start)
            rank = text[start:end]

            start = text.find('"% High Job Meaning":"',start)
            start += len('"% High Job Meaning":"')
            end = text.find('"',start)
            high_job = text[start:end]

            start = text.find('"School Type":"',start)
            start += len('"School Type":"')
            end = text.find('"',start)
            school_type = text[start:end]

            start = text.find('"% STEM":"',start)
            start += len('"% STEM":"')
            end = text.find('"',start)
            stem = text[start:end]

            list_to_write.append([rank,school_name,school_type,early_pay,mid_pay,high_job,stem])
writer.writerows(list_to_write)
file_name.close()
```

This will generate your necessary table in csv. Don't forget to close the file when you are done.

Comment: **Thank you** @Khairul Your code (almost) works. I had to delete _newline=""_  because python argues that it wouldn't take this parameter into the _open()_ function. When I looked up in order to learn it, I saw that it's a new parameter introduced for python 3.

I'm talking about this line:
`file_name = open("table.csv","w",newline="")` 

This is super helpful -> thanks.

Comment: I coded in python 3.5 and sorry i didn't know it's a new parameter in python 3 otherwise i would have mentioned. @oba2311

Comment: No worries @Khairul you indeed solved the problem! hence the check - thanks.

Comment: I reviewed again your response to deepen my learning. I realized that I'm not sure why and how did you pick `html.parser` since in BS documentation `LXML` and others are recommended to deal with HTML.
I looked here: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

@metame also didn't answer this question in his response. thanks!

Comment: @oba2311 there's not much difference actually, between 'html.parser' and 'lxml'.

Comment: it'd be very useful if you can point me towards a clear explanation for how you parsed the js section. Specifically, the syntax for the chunks:
            `start = text.find('"Mid-Career Median Pay":"',start)
            start += len('"Mid-Career Median Pay":"')
            end = text.find('"',start)
            mid_pay = text[start:end]`

Answer (score 2):

While this won't find the table that's not in `r.text`, you are asking `BeautifulSoup` to use the `xml` parser instead of `html.parser` so I would recommend changing that line to:

`soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')`

One of the issues you will run into with web scraping is what are called "client-rendered" websites versus server-rendered.  Basically, this means that the page you would get from a basic html request through the `requests` module or through `curl` for example is not the same content that would be rendered in a web browser.  Some of the common frameworks for this are React and Angular.  If you examine the source of the page you are wanting to scrape, they have `data-react-id`s on several of their html elements.  A common tell for Angular pages are similar element attributes with the prefix `ng`, e.g. `ng-if` or `ng-bind`.  You can see the page's source in Chrome or Firefox through their respective dev tools, which can be launched with the keyboard shortcut `Ctrl+Shift+I` in either browser.  It's worth noting that not all React & Angular pages are only client-rendered.

In order to get this sort of content, you would need to use a headless browser tool like [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/). There are many resources on web scraping with Selenium and Python.

Answer (score 2):

The data is located in JavaScript variable, you should find the js text data then use regex to extract it. when you get the data, it's json list object which contains 900+ school dict, you should use json module to load it to python list obejct.

```
import requests, bs4, re, json

url = "http://www.payscale.com/college-salary-report/bachelors?page=65"
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
var = soup.find(text=re.compile('collegeSalaryReportData'))
table_text = re.search(r'collegeSalaryReportData = (\[.+\]);\n    var', var, re.DOTALL).group(1)
table_data = json.loads(table_text)
pprint(table_data)
print('The number of school', len(table_data))
```

out:

```
 {'% Female': '0.57',
  '% High Job Meaning': 'N/A',
  '% Male': '0.43',
  '% Pell': 'N/A',
  '% STEM': '0.1',
  '% who Recommend School': 'N/A',
  'Division 1 Basketball Classifications': 'Not Division 1 Basketball',
  'Division 1 Football Classifications': 'Not Division 1 Football',
  'Early Career Median Pay': '36200',
  'IPEDS ID': '199643',
  'ImageUrl': '/content/school_logos/Shaw University_50px.png',
  'Mid-Career Median Pay': '45600',
  'Rank': '963',
  'School Name': 'Shaw University',
  'School Sector': 'Private not-for-profit',
  'School Type': 'Private School, Religious',
  'State': 'North Carolina',
  'Undergraduate Enrollment': '1664',
  'Url': '/research/US/School=Shaw_University/Salary',
  'Zip Code': '27601'}]
The number of school 963
```