# Scraping data from a website to get a table, but I am getting an empty table

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the table from this [website](http://www.peaklist.org/WWlists/WorldTop50.html) but I am getting an empty csv file, containing only the header.

I tried the code from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42310252/scraping-a-table-from-a-page-using-beautifulsoup-table-is-not-found). I don't know what is happening with my code, why is it returning an empty table.

My code:

```
url = "http://www.peaklist.org/WWlists/WorldTop50.html"
r = requests.get(url)
data= r.text

soup=BeautifulSoup(data,"html.parser")
scripts = soup.find_all("script")
file_name = open("table.csv","w",newline="")
writer = csv.writer(file_name)

list_to_write = []

list_to_write.append(["Summit Name", "Country", "Lat.", "Long.", "Elevation mtrs.", "Prom. mtrs.", "Saddle mtrs.", "Saddle Location", "Elevation ft.", "Prom. ft.", "Notes", "Aerial Photo" ])

for script in scripts:
   text = script.text
   start = 0
   end = 0
   if(len(text) > 10000):
       while(start > -1):
           start = text.find('"Summit Name":"',start)
           if(start == -1):
               break
           start += len('"Summit Name":"')
           end = text.find('"',start)
           summit_name = text[start:end]

           #start = text.find('"Summit Name":"',start)
           #start += len('"Summit Name":"')
           #end = text.find('"',start)
           #summit_name = text[start:end]

           start = text.find('"Country":"',start)
           start += len('"Country":"')
           end = text.find('"',start)
           country = text[start:end]

           start = text.find('"Lat.":"',start)
           start += len('"Lat":"')
           end = text.find('"',start)
           lat = text[start:end]

           start = text.find('"Long.":"',start)
           start += len('"Long.":"')
           end = text.find('"',start)
           long = text[start:end]

           start = text.find('"Elevation mtrs.":"',start)
           start += len('"Elevation mtrs.":"')
           end = text.find('"',start)
           elevation = text[start:end]

           start = text.find('"Prom. mtrs.":"',start)
           start += len('"Prom. mtrs.":"')
           end = text.find('"',start)
           prom = text[start:end]

           start = text.find('"Saddle mtrs.":"',start)
           start += len('"Saddle mtrs.":"')
           end = text.find('"',start)
           saddle = text[start:end]

           start = text.find('"Saddle Location":"',start)
           start += len('"Saddle Location":"')
           end = text.find('"',start)
           saddle_loc = text[start:end]

           start = text.find('"Elevation ft.":"',start)
           start += len('"Elevation ft.":"')
           end = text.find('"',start)
           elevation_ft = text[start:end]

           start = text.find('"Prom. ft.":"',start)
           start += len('"Prom. ft.":"')
           end = text.find('"',start)
           prom_ft = text[start:end]

           start = text.find('"Notes":"',start)
           start += len('"Notes":"')
           end = text.find('"',start)
           notes = text[start:end]

           start = text.find('"Aerial Photo":"',start)
           start += len('"Aerial Photo":"')
           end = text.find('"',start)
           aerial = text[start:end]

           list_to_write.append([summit_name,country,lat,long,elevation,prom,saddle,saddle_loc,elevation_ft,prom_ft,notes,aerial])
writer.writerows(list_to_write)
file_name.close()
```

I am not getting an error message for this code, just an empty table so I think maybe this method does not recognize the table data in the website?

Thanks !!

Comment: I think the problem is in your logic

Comment: What is the expected output? Post some lines from the csv you expect.

Comment: @Jarvis the csv file should contain the following columns: summit_name,country,lat,long,elevation,prom,saddle,saddle_loc,elevation_ft,prom_ft,notes,aerial

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in the way you are iterating thorugh your data.
In the future, try to logically think through your program while writing it, such as using the correct tag names in `find_all` and using the most fault tolerant way of iterating through the data that you're scraping.

This script isn't perfect but I think it can guide you in better understanding how to scrape. Check the comments to understand what the code does.

```
url = "http://www.peaklist.org/WWlists/WorldTop50.html"
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,"html.parser")

to_csv = [["Summit Name", "Country", "Lat.", "Long.", "Elevation mtrs.", "Prom. mtrs.", "Saddle mtrs.", "Saddle Location", "Elevation ft.", "Prom. ft.", "Notes", "Aerial Photo" ]]

table = soup.find_all('table')[1] # Chose the second table on the page
rows = table.find_all('tr') # Get all table rows from our table element

del rows[0] # Remove the first row which is the table heading (we already have it)

for row in rows:
    tmp = [] # We're gonna add our column data in this list
    columns = row.find_all('td') # Find all columns in the row
    for column in columns:
        tmp.append(column.text.strip()) # strip() is used to remove extra space from the text
    
    to_csv.append(tmp) # Append this list to the main list

with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    for row in to_csv: # For each list in the main list
        line = ','.join(row) # We're gonna join the column data in row
        csvfile.write(line) # Write each line to the file
```

Comment: thanks, I tried this but still getting an empty csv file...

Comment: Try the new solution

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the tips. The code below worked well:

```
url="http://www.peaklist.org/WWlists/WorldTop50.html"
html_content = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")
gdp = soup.find_all("tr")
print("Number of rows on site: ",len(gdp))
body_rows = gdp[2:]

all_rows = []

for row_num in range(len(body_rows)): 
    row = [] 
    for row_item in body_rows[row_num].find_all("td"): 
        aa = re.sub("(\xa0)|(\n)|,","",row_item.text)
        row.append(aa)
        
    all_rows.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=all_rows)
```

I checked the html code before that so that is why gdp starts from row 2.